# display div over another when click a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

i would like to display a div over another when click on a link
here is the html and css code :

```
<div id="desc" class="desc">some text</div>
<div id="awards" class="awards">some other text</div>
<a href="#">click</a>

.desc {
border:1px solid #000;
height:170px;
width:330px;
}
.awards {
border:1px solid #000;
height:170px;
width:330px;
display:none;
}
```

with transition if it's possible.

i made an example i want desc disappear and awards apear
http://jsfiddle.net/06nsd1y3/

Comment: Try to only post code that is relevant to your question, this will make more people read the question and it will be easier to help you. Also include what you already tried to solve the problem in your question, that encourages people to help as they do not feel like you want them to work for you (and they have somewhere to start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care to come back to the initial state then Javascript is not necessary: just use CSS with `:target` pseudoclass

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/03vqnoob/

---

Markup:

```
<div id="desc" class="desc">some text</div>
<div id="awards" class="awards">some other text</div>
<a href="#desc">click</a>
```

CSS:

```
div:target {
    display: none;
}

div:target + div  {
    display: block;
}
```

If you also need a transition you may play with the `opacity` property, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/w17p6o5d/

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript

```js
function fun()
    {
        document.getElementById("desc").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("awards").style.display="block";
    }
```

```css
.desc {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:170px;
    width:330px;
  
}
.awards {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:170px;
    width:330px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="desc" class="desc">some text</div>
<div id="awards" class="awards">some other text</div>
<a href="#" onclick="fun();">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most simplest jQuery -

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#desc').fadeOut();
  $('#awards').fadeIn();
});
```

See [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) for full documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/06nsd1y3/1/

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#desc').hide();
    $('#awards').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Toggle function.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#desc').toggle();
  $('#awards').toggle();
});
```